# Creating Hive Database connection using apache distribution in talend

Tags: apache, hive, talend

I am new to talend!
I am trying to create a hive db connection using apache distribution (apache 1.0.0(hive0.9.0)).
I am using server name as : "talend-hdp-all" as given in the talend tutorial.
But the connection is not successful. maybe its because of wrong server or port number.
Can anyone please help me to know what is my "server name" and "port number".

Comment: Do you have the Hive service running? What steps have you followed to set up Hive? How have you configured your tHiveConnection component?

Answer (score 1):

You need to follow these steps

1) First make your hadoop is running on port 9000 or 8020 as you have specified in hadoop core-site.xml file using netstat -nl|grep portno

2)start your hive server using start --service hiveserver and it runs by default on port 10000

3) Your hive port no would be 10000.

This will definately solve your issue.